# How to add groupBy option WITH ROLLUP

Tags: database

With Drupal 9.5.3, a group by like this:

```
$query->groupBy("myfieldname WITH ROLLUP");
```

will result in

> (...) Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'myfieldnameWITHROLLUP' (...)

... since spaces are stripped.

Is there any other proper way to add the "WITH ROLLUP"?

Comment: Looks like currently it's not possible using Drupal's dynamic query API. See [Support ROLLUP modifier for GROUP BY](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1647884). I would try using a [static query](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api/static-queries) as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @NoSssweat, that's what I've done for now.